# Crossing a bridge?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Let's say you have to get to the other side of the river by using a hanging bridge or the like. Could you say:

> You have to **cross this bridge** before you get to the other side

Is this correct?

Comment: It's grammatically correct but unusual. People would usually say **..to get to the other side**.

Comment: Hmm, I see... but this is because I need to use this 'cross this bridge' phrase for future use and not just in here, you know, for better expression or the like.

Comment: If you google **cross the bridge**, **cross this bridge** or **cross that bridge** you will find numerous examples of its usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence sounds like it's expressing a pre-requisite (something one is required to do in advance) for getting to the other side rather than explaining *the means by which* one gets to the other side. Compare:

"You have to take off your shoes before you enter my home."

"You have to walk up my front steps to enter my home."

"You have to walk up my front steps in order to enter my home."

So the sentence you're looking for is "You have to cross this bridge to get to the other side" or "You have to cross this bridge in order to get to the other side."

Comment: So this means that, I have to change 'before' into 'in order to' or 'to' instead? To make it sound a bit casual right?

Comment: You have to change "before you" to "in order to" or "to".